# Change Mac Address on Nexus 7 running 4.2.2

Tags: wi-fi, nexus-7, mac-address

My question is: How do I change/spoof the mac address of my Nexus 7 so that the router sees the spoofed address and will not give an authentication error when connecting?

I have done some looking around, and I have tried apps like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=diewland.changemac&feature=search_result), ip link and if config, and editing my nvram.txt file, but none of these methods appear to work. Has anyone had any luck with this? My tablet is running the faux Kernel with KaosDroid if it helps.

Comment: You're not trying to hack your way into another one's network, do you? Assuming you're not, the only other thing I know is [Wireless Mac Changer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wireless.macchanger).

Comment: That app seems to run the same command as the other app, just with a different interface. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I didn't expect a "Boah eye!" effect -- but thought it might be worth a try, though :) Sorry it wasn't much help -- but it was all I could come up with here...